# Gulp: run task without a destination

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm trying to make a simple task to show the file size for each file in an array of paths using the `gulp-size` package, like so:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var size = require('gulp-size')

gulp.task('size', function() {
  gulp.src(bigArrayOfFilePathsFromAnotherModule)
    .pipe(size({ showFiles: true }))
})
```

When this runs, it gets part of the way through, but then the task finishes before all of the files are processed. It works just fine if I pipe them to a destination, but I'd rather not copy the files anywhere. Is there a way to pipe these files into a black hole so the task completes?

I've tried `.pipe(gulp.dest('/dev/null'))` but it errors out trying to `mkdir /dev/null` which already exists.

Is there a good way to pipe a stream to nowhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should return your stream:

```
gulp.task('size', function() {
  return gulp.src(bigArrayOfFilePathsFromAnotherModule)
    .pipe(size({ showFiles: true }));
})
```

Otherwise, gulp will assume the work done by the task is synchronous and done by the time your anonymous function returns.